# .Net Core HttpClientFactory dispose HttpClientHandler

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am currently configuring my `httpclientfactory` this way

```
HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; }

};

serviceCollection.AddHttpClient("ignoreSSL", c =>
{}).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(h => httpClientHandler);
```

To disable the validation of security certificates, but when doing too many requests I receive this exception:

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'SocketsHttpHandler'.

I currently build my `httpclient` this way

```
HttpClient client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("ignoreSSL");
```

Doing tests, this is solved in this way without `httpclientfactory`

```
HttpClient ad = new HttpClient(handler, false);
```

For more than I look for I can not find how to tell `httpclientfactory` not to make handler dispose?

Comment: HttpClientFactory works as it *should*. The pooled HttpClientHandlers *must* be cleaned periodically to handle changing DNS registrations. Where was this error raised?

Comment: Why do you create a *single* HttpClientHandler explicitly like that? You'll end up with multiple HttpClients all trying to use the *same* connection instead of a pool of connections. If you want to disable HTTPS certificate errors, use HttpClientFactory's configuration methods to set handler properties

Comment: The problem is caused because `ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler` is used to return the *same* handler each time instead of creating a new one

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is caused because a *single* HttpClientHandler  instance is used for all requests. It's the HttpClientFactory's job to manage, pool and recycle handlers.

It looks like the *actual* question is how to disable certificate validation when using HttpClientFactory. This requires configuring the client handlers used by it.

[As the documentation shows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-the-httpmessagehandler) this is done using the [ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientbuilderextensions.configureprimaryhttpmessagehandler?view=aspnetcore-2.2) method. From the method's remarks :

> **Remarks**
>
> The delegate should return a new instance of the message handler each time it is invoked.

The handlers created by that method will be added to a handler pool and used by other handlers like Polly's retry handlers. HttpClientFactory will recycle older handlers to handle DNS registration changes.

The code should look like this:

```
services.AddHttpClient<HttpWrapper>("ignoreSSL")
        .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
        {
            return new HttpClientHandler
            {
                ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (m, crt, chn, e) => true
            };
        });
```